# Login through Google or Facebook not returning to application

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, xcode7, ios9.2

I've recently upgraded to Xcode(7.2). Before upgrading everything was working fine(i.e. in Xcode 6.3) but after upgrading I'm facing an issue that after choosing login through Google or Facebook, it is not getting back to the app.

[image]

Comment: Please post actual code and not a screenshot of the code you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be because of

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

and

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
```

of `UIApplicationDelegate` got deprecated. You should switch to:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options`
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I ve added a screenshot. Please suggest something from that

Comment: Got that working for fb but when I add same thing for google then it's showing duplicate method. How to differentiate them?